# Send funds using RPC call in blockchain

Tags: blockchain

In Bitcoin or Qtum, is there any way to send funds from address to address using an RPC call or a CLI command? The source address and target address are both in my wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Using qtum-cli, you can use **sendtoaddress**, which has a *senderaddress* argument:

> sendtoaddress "address" amount ( "comment" "comment_to"
>   subtractfeefromamount )
>
> Send an amount to a given address.
>
> Arguments:
>   1. "address"            (string, required) The qtum address to send to.
>   2. "amount"             (numeric or string, required) The amount in QTUM to send. eg 0.1
>
> ...
>
> 6. "senderaddress"      (string, optional) The quantum address that will be used to send money from."

Example:

```
sendtoaddress "QM72Sfpbz1BPpXFHz9m3CdqATR44Jvaydd" 0.1 "" "" "" "QPPhude3Euck6FWUdyRXdVJPUnLseGGWM1"
```